# PHP - parse data from a SOAP response

Tags: php, soap, curl, w3c-validation

I'm using the W3 validator API, and I get this kind of response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Body>
<m:markupvalidationresponse env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator">

    <m:uri>http://myurl.com/</m:uri>
    <m:checkedby>http://validator.w3.org/</m:checkedby>
    <m:doctype>-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN</m:doctype>
    <m:charset>utf-8</m:charset>
    <m:validity>false</m:validity>
    <m:errors>
        <m:errorcount>1</m:errorcount>
        <m:errorlist>

            <m:error>
                <m:line>7</m:line>
                <m:col>80</m:col>
                <m:message>character data is not allowed here</m:message>
                <m:messageid>63</m:messageid>
                <m:explanation>  <![CDATA[
                 PAGE HTML IS HERE
                  ]]>
                </m:explanation>
                <m:source><![CDATA[ HTML AGAIN ]]></m:source>
            </m:error>

            ...

        </m:errorlist>
    </m:errors>
    <m:warnings>
        <m:warningcount>0</m:warningcount>
        <m:warninglist>


        </m:warninglist>
    </m:warnings>
</m:markupvalidationresponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

How can I extract some variables from there?

I need `validity`, `errorcount` and if possible from the list of errors: `line`, `col`, and `message` :)

Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php, its called simple for a reason

Comment: can I use simplepie for this? - http://simplepie.org/

Comment: Simplepie is specifically for RSS, and this is not an RSS feed. You should either use a SOAP client library, like David suggested, or use SimpleXML to parse the XML yourself. Once you decide which approach you like, I could write some example code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the XML string into a `SimpleXMLElement` with `simplexml_load_string` and then find the attributes using XPath. It's important to register the namespaces involved with `registerXPathNamespace` before using XPath.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('example.xml'); // $xml should be the XML source string
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$doc->registerXPathNamespace('m', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator');
$nodes = $doc->xpath('//m:markupvalidationresponse/m:validity');
$validity = strval($nodes[0]);
echo 'is valid: ', $validity, "\n";
$nodes = $doc->xpath('//m:markupvalidationresponse/m:errors/m:errorcount');
$errorcount = strval($nodes[0]);
echo 'total errors: ', $errorcount, "\n";
$nodes = $doc->xpath('//m:markupvalidationresponse/m:errors/m:errorlist/m:error');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $nodes = $node->xpath('m:line'); 
    $line = strval($nodes[0]);
    $nodes = $node->xpath('m:col');
    $col = strval($nodes[0]);
    $nodes = $node->xpath('m:message');
    $message = strval($nodes[0]);
    echo 'line: ', $line, ', column: ', $col, ' message: ', $message, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a SOAP library to get this in the first place. There are various options you can try for this; nusoap,  http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php, the zend framework also has SOAP client and server which you can use. Whatever implementation you use will allow you to get the data in some way. Doing a var_dump() on whatever holds the initial response should aid you in navigating through it.

Answer (score 3):

If you rather use the [DOMDocument class from php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). You don't have to know Xpath to get this working. An example:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=".urlencode($url)."&output=soap12"); 

$doctype = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator', 'doctype')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$valid = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator', 'validity')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$errorcount = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator', 'errorcount')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$warningcount = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator', 'warningcount')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$errors = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator', 'error');
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo "<br>line: ".$error->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
    echo "<br>col: ".$error->childNodes->item(3)->nodeValue;
    echo "<br>message: ".$error->childNodes->item(5)->nodeValue;
}
```

// item() arguments are uneven because the empty text between tags is counted as an item.