# Getting value from SOAP response in php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I am getting a SOAP response for a SOAP call perfectly using SOAP ui but when I call the same in php, I am not able to traverse to the desired element(**CreditId** in this case), which I want.

The following is the SOAP response that I get using SOAP ui :

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header/>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:getProjectCreditListResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <EUserGuid>33/XIcx+3/GxWABQVoJXWA==</EUserGuid>
         <EtCurrCreditList>
            <item>
               <PhaseId/>
               <CreditcategoryDescrption>Project Information Forms</CreditcategoryDescrption>
               <CreditId>CSD1GSP1L-1000008140</CreditId>
            </item>
            <item>
               <PhaseId/>
               <CreditcategoryDescrption>Project Information Forms</CreditcategoryDescrption>
               <CreditId>CSD1GSP2L-1000008140</CreditId>
            </item>
</EtCurrCreditList>
         <EtErrorLogInfo/>
      </n0:getProjectCreditListResponse>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Now I have gone through the various similar questions on the site, where it is advised to do like this to get the desired element :

```
$client = new SoapClient('wsdl file path',array('trace'=>1,'exceptions'=>1);
$res = $client->getCreditFormDataXml(array(input arguments));

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($res);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap-env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('n0', 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style');
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//EtCurrCreditList//item//CreditId') as $item)
    {
        var_dump($item);
    }
```

However I get an error stating that

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string

I have tried converting the **$res** variable to a string but it gives an error that

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

But if I do **var_dump($res)**, I get output like this :

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'EUserGuid' => string 'ß×!Ì~ßñ±X�PV‚WX' (length=16)
  public 'EtCurrCreditList' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'EtErrorLogInfo' => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
```

**Why is the code not going to the sub nodes of the EtCurrCreditList so that I can then process it to get the desired value.** - Solved

Final Output :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [EUserGuid] => ß×!Ì~ßñ±XPV‚WX
    [EtCurrCreditList] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [PhaseId] => 
                            [PhaseDescription] => 
                            [CreditcategoryId] => CSD1GSL-1000008140
                            [CreditcategoryDescrption] => Project Information Forms
                            [CreditId] => CSD1GSP1L-1000008140
                         )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [PhaseId] => 
                            [PhaseDescription] => 
                            [CreditcategoryId] => CSD1GSL-1000008140
                            [CreditcategoryDescrption] => Project Information Forms
                            [CreditId] => CSD1GSP2L-1000008140
            )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [PhaseId] => 
                            [PhaseDescription] => 
                            [CreditcategoryId] => CSD1GSL-1000008140
                            [CreditcategoryDescrption] => Project Information Forms
                            [CreditId] => CSD1GSP3L-1000008140
            )
        )

        )

    [EtErrorLogInfo] => stdClass Object
        (
        )
```

Comment: Try this.this may solve your queries

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048685/php-parse-data-from-a-soap-response

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I am following these steps only, but the problem is that **simplexml_load_string** function is not recognizing **$res** as a string,, so how do I solve this problem first.

Also I tried copying the xml and using that as an input and then executing the above code, it gives all the creditID's but not through using **$res** as input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `echo"<pre>";print_r($res);` you will be better able to understand how to traverse or show  us the result.

```
$res=stdClass Object ( [EUserGuid] => ß×!Ì~ßñ±XPV‚WX [EtCurrCreditList] => stdClass Object ( ) [EtErrorLogInfo] => stdClass Object ( ) )
```

Now use

```
foreach($res->EUserGuid as $data)
       {
         //Your logic 
       }
```

same for `EtCurrCreditList` and `EtErrorLogInfo` and also nested loops if these object contain anything.

updating according to your new output.
you can iterate it like this

```
$res->EUserGuid=$something;

foreach($res->EtCurrCreditList->item as $eachItem)
{
    $eachItem->PhaseId=$your_ wish;
    $eachItem->PhaseDescription==$your_ wish;
    $eachItem->CreditcategoryId==$your_ wish;
    $eachItem->CreditcategoryDescrption==$your_ wish;
    $eachItem->CreditId=$your_ wish;
}
```

and can ignore `EtErrorLogInfo`

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment @rahulRaj.
I did that and the output I am getting is : 
`stdClass Object
(
    [EUserGuid] => ß×!Ì~ßñ±XPV‚WX
    [EtCurrCreditList] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [EtErrorLogInfo] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)`

So it seems that its not traversing the nodes of EtCurrCreditList,, could you suggest any specific reason for that.

Comment: Hi thanks again for the response, I tried using code to fetch the CreditID and ran this :
 
`foreach($res->EtCurrCreditList as $val1 )
{
     
     foreach($val1->item as $val2)
     {
          foreach($val2->CreditId as $val)
          {
               print_r($val);
          }
     }
}`

Now I am not getting any output just blank screen,, no error or anything is showing.

Any help on what to do to get the creditId..??

Comment: from the response you can see thre is value only for EUserGuid rest all are empty,

Comment: yes you are right,, i am not getting any values for EtCurrCreditList, but when I use the wsdl to check the response in soapUI, I can see values in EtCurrCreditList too. Why is the SoapClient not giving those values ? Any clue ?

Comment: can you give the wsdl url and set of input values you are supplying in array(input arguments)

Comment: I dont have the url but have the wsdl file itself and it is very large to post here,, but I am sure that the input parameters I am adding are correct as they are giving right results in the soapUI.

Comment: Thanks for the help, solved the problem in which I had not given the complete input parameters. Now I am getting the values in EtCurrCreditlist, but now if I run the code, I get the error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` which is corresponding to the line - `foreach($val1->item as $val2`
I searched for this and found that since `item` is an array type, i cannot access it like an object using `-> notation`,I have also tried other ways of accessing it but its not working,,how do I access all the item nodes and the corresponding CreditId from that.?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the main post with response, please have a look at it.